# Install RKE2 Kubernetes on Hardened Linux

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I'm trying to install RKE2 on a virtual Rocky Linux 8 server, with "minimal server install" and a CIS Server Level 2 hardening profile, but when I start the service, I get some errors. Always when I install on a server with separate /var partition (which is required by the hardening profile), I have this issue.

When I start the service (systemctl start rke2-server.service) with root user, I give the following response:

### Apr 25 18:24:45 server.companyeli.local rke2[3351]: time="2023-04-25T18:24:45-03:00" level=info msg="Updated manifest /var/lib/rancher/rke2/server/manifests/harvester-csi-driver.yaml to set clust>
Apr 25 18:24:45 server.companyeli.local rke2[3351]: time="2023-04-25T18:24:45-03:00" level=info msg="Updated manifest /var/lib/rancher/rke2/server/manifests/rke2-calico-crd.yaml to set cluster co>
Apr 25 18:24:45 server.companyeli.local rke2[3351]: time="2023-04-25T18:24:45-03:00" level=info msg="Updated manifest /var/lib/rancher/rke2/server/manifests/rke2-multus.yaml to set cluster config>
Apr 25 18:24:45 server.companyeli.local rke2[3351]: time="2023-04-25T18:24:45-03:00" level=info msg="Updated manifest /var/lib/rancher/rke2/server/manifests/rke2-snapshot-controller.yaml to set c>
Apr 25 18:24:45 server.companyeli.local rke2[3351]: time="2023-04-25T18:24:45-03:00" level=info msg="Logging containerd to /var/lib/rancher/rke2/agent/containerd/containerd.log"
Apr 25 18:24:45 server.companyeli.local rke2[3351]: time="2023-04-25T18:24:45-03:00" level=info msg="Running containerd -c /var/lib/rancher/rke2/agent/etc/containerd/config.toml -a /run/k3s/conta>
Apr 25 18:24:45 server.companyeli.local rke2[3351]: containerd: fork/exec /var/lib/rancher/rke2/data/v1.25.9-rke2r1-177f016694ea/bin/containerd: permission denied
Apr 25 18:24:45 server.companyeli.local systemd[1]: rke2-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 25 18:24:45 server.companyeli.local systemd[1]: rke2-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- The unit rke2-server.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 25 18:24:45 server.companyeli.local systemd[1]: Failed to start Rancher Kubernetes Engine v2 (server).
-- Subject: Unit rke2-server.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

On step 3 of the quick rancher tutorial (https://docs.rke2.io/install/quickstart), I have the error above that start with a permission denied on /var/lib/rancher/rke2/data/v1.25.9-rke2r1-177f016694ea/bin/containerd. I changed the /var directory permissions and owner, without success..

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by editing the /etc/fstab file, change the *noexec* to *exec* on /var partition.